# system.stackoverflowexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll in linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Below is my current LINQ:

```
var parentChildIds = (from pcIds in unitOfWork.ParentChildRelation.Fetch()
                       join longVal in arrLongVal
                       on pcIds.Parent_Child_ID equals longVal
                       select new
                       {
                           ParentID = pcIds.Mapping_Source_ID,
                           ChildID = longVal 
                       }).ToList();
```

where `arrLongVal` is array of `long` that may contain 500 long values. It is working fine when array is having 100-150 records. When i am running above query for more number of records it is giving me

> System.StackOverflowException occurred in mscorlib.dll` exception.

I tried changing above query as

```
var parentChildIds = (from pcIds in unitOfWork.ParentChildRelation.Fetch()
                       where arrLongVal.Contains(pcIds.Parent_Child_ID)
                       select new
                       {
                          ParentID = pcIds.Mapping_Source_ID,
                          ChildID = arrLongVal
                                 .Where(obj => obj == pcIds.Parent_Child_ID)
                                 .Select(obj=> obj).FirstOrDefault()
                       }).ToList();
```

But this is also not working. Please help.

Comment: What's the code of `unitOfWork.ParentChildRelation.Fetch()` ? A `System.StackOverflowException` in this case probably means you have an endless loop somewhere. Since you are working with parent/child relations I think it might be related to that code.

Comment: Are you getting the same error with second method?  Try a simple for loop instead of linq and see if you also getting an overflow exception.

Comment: In your second attempt the `.Select(obj => obj)` is completely redundant.

Comment: I am using entitty framework that is why added `unitOfWork.ParentChildRelation.Fetch()` to get records from DB. Also i am not usinf any loop or anything. It is just join on array and DB records.